# Yii2 kartik typeahead not working with wbraganca dynamic form

Tags: jquery, yii2, typeahead, dynamicform

Hi I am having problems with typeahead and dynamic form working together. Only the first item works but when I add another item typeahead is not working as it is suppose to be.Here's how I use typeahead

```
<?= $form->field($item, "[{$index}]code")->widget(Typeahead::classname(), [
          'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose from existing or enter new code'],
          'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true, 'minLength' => 3],
          'scrollable' => true,
          'dataset' => [
                            [
                                'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                                'display' => 'value',
                                'prefetch' => Url::to(['app/app-codes']),
                                'remote' => [
                                      'url' => Url::to(['app/code']) . '?q=%QUERY',
                                      'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                                 ],
                                 'limit' => 100,
                            ]
                       ]
          ]); ?>
```

My jquery

```
<?php

$js = '

jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {

        jQuery(this).html("Items: " + (index + 1))

        jQuery("#item" +(index + 1) + "-code").parent().typeahead({highlight:true, minLength:3});
    });

});


jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {

        jQuery(this).html("Items: " + (index + 1))

        jQuery("#item" +(index + 1) + "-code").parent().typeahead({highlight:true, minLength:3});

    });

});

';


$this->registerJs($js);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution **using clean typeahead.js** without kartik-v

1) Define asset
https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js

Css: https://github.com/bassjobsen/typeahead.js-bootstrap-css

Instructions how define if you do not know: https://toster.ru/q/142561#answer_item_1377456

```php
\app\assets\TypeaheadAsset::register($this);
```

2)

```php
<?= $form->field($modelTz, "[{$ind}]tz_number")->textInput(['class'=>'form-control tz_number', 'autocomplete'=>'off']) ?>
```

3) Add after `DynamicFormWidget::end();`

```js
<script>
    function typeaheadInit(){
        $('.tz_number').typeahead('destroy').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 2
            },
            {
                name: 'typeAhead1',
                source: new Bloodhound({datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace, queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    remote: {
                        url: '<?=Url::to(['/site/ajax-find-tz']) . '?q=%QUERY'?>',
                        wildcard: '%QUERY'
                    }
                }),
                display: "value",
                templates:{"suggestion": function (d) { return '<p>' + d.value + ' - ' + d.customer + '</p>'; }}
            }
        );
    }
    $(function () {
        typeaheadInit();

        $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function() {
            typeaheadInit();
        });
    });
</script>
```